# Maximize sum of two numbers plus distance between them

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

We are given square matrix of numbers, e.g.

```
1 9 2
3 8 3
2 1 1
```

The distance between adjacent numbers is `2`. We want to find such two numbers, in the same row or in the same column, that their sum plus the distance between them is maximal. For example, in the example above, such numbers are `9` and `8` and the max result is `9+8+1*2 = 19`. We want to find just the maximal result, we don't need which specific numbers sum to it.

That looks like a DP problem for me, but I can't think of any elegant solution.

Comment: How large matrix can be?

Comment: Let's say that `n <= 1000`, so max. `10^6` numbers in matrix.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One can solve the 1D problem (that is, given a list of numbers, find the pair which maximizes sum+distance) using dynamic programming.

```
bi = 0
best = -10**9  # anything large and negative
for i in range(1, n+1):
   best = max(best, a[i] + a[bi] + (i - bi)*2)
   if a[i] - i*2 > a[bi] - bi*2:
      bi = i
```

After this code finishes, `best` will store the maximum sum + distance of any pair of numbers in the list. It works because at any given loop iteration of `i`, `bi` stores the index of the value at index less than `i` that maximizes its value minus twice its index. One can observe that the number at this index is the best number (to the left of `i`) to pair the number at `i` with.

Once you have this, the 2D problem is straightforward: go through each row and column and apply the 1D algorithm, and return the maximum pair found. Overall for an `n` by `n` matrix, this runs in O(n^2) time, which is clearly asymptotically optimal since every element in the matrix needs to be read at least once.

Here is working Python3 code:

```
def max_sum_dist_1D(a):
    bi = 0
    best = -10**9
    for i in range(1, len(a)):
        best = max(best, a[i] + a[bi] + (i - bi)*2)
        if a[i] - i*2 > a[bi] - bi*2:
            bi = i
    return best

def max_sum_dist_2D(M):
    best_row = max(max_sum_dist_1D(row) for row in M)
    best_col = max(max_sum_dist_1D(col) for col in zip(*M))
    return max(best_row, best_col)

M = [[1, 9, 2], [3, 8, 3], [2, 1, 1]]

print(max_sum_dist_2D(M))
```

Comment: Thanks @maraca . I'd missed the part in the question about the distance between adjacent elements being 2.

Comment: @PaulHankin ' I'd missed the part in the question' thats a - score on the `attention to detail` :)